# Determining intermediate pressure between two turbines

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics

> A steam power plant employs two adiabatic turbines in series. Steam
>   enters the first turbine at 650 C and 7000 kPa and discharges from the
>   second turbine at 20 kPa. The system is designed for equal power
>   outputs from the two turbines, based on a turbine efficienct of 78%
>   for each turbine. Determine the temperature and pressure of the system
>   in its intermediate state between the two turbines. What is the
>   overall efficiency of the two turbines together with respect to
>   isentropic expansion of the steam from the initial to final state.

How should I determine the pressure between two turbines?I have the [solution](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2xNtfJLGsLwZ3ZnNWxQS283ZXM/edit) from a solution manual (prob. 8.6) but I just can't understand why it takes pressures around 700 KPa and does an interpolation.
what we know:

$S3=S2=S1$ (if working isentropically) ($S$ is entropy)

$x$ (Quality of exiting vapor)

Note:we could determine properties of the intermediate flow properties using one property($S$) just if it's two-phase, but it's assumed that the intermediate flow is superheated.

I'm sure of problem's data and that's all we have.

Comment: "i have a solution but i just don't understand why it takes pressures around 700 KPa and does an interpolation... " mind if you would share that bit? S3=S2=S1 shall this just illustrate that this is an isentropic process? What is S?

Comment: @idkfa $S$ is the entropy.

Comment: @Mohammad Are you sure there are no other given data? and please edit your answer and include your solution and assumptions.

Comment: @Algo updated the question.

Comment: In response to your recent edit: You are withholding information, you have a solution that you do not share. If you want to keep us in the dark the question will likely be closed. How can we explain what was done if we don't get to see it?

Comment: @idkfa no i'm absolutely not trying to keep you in the dark ! I just want too see others approach to the problem! cause i really don't understand what solution did.
if you are interested in solution here it is     :    https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2xNtfJLGsLwZ3ZnNWxQS283ZXM/      problem 8.6

Comment: No, you didn't you just improved the formatting ;). again, the data you provided are incomplete. At worst, I would assume that the two turbines work at the same pressure ratio yielding: $$ P_2 = \sqrt{P_1P_3} $$

Comment: @algo it's all the problem, i added the picture.

Comment: See, you didn't mention that both turbines generate same power.

Comment: @Algo that results h3-h2=h2-h1 ? i'll be happy if you provide an answer.

Comment: @MohammadHoseinKhalili. Your link to the solution has many answer solutions. I suggest that you use the snip tool (on window 7) or equivalent and extract to relevant section.

Comment: The solution manual states that "the work difference is linear in P2" which I think is a bit dubious.  I can't think of one thermodynamic property of steam that is linear with respect to pressure.

Comment: @Carlton i think that's just a bad approximation coming from dW=PdV

Comment: @MohammadHoseinKhalili: Yes, $\int PdV$ is for ideal gasses, which steam is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer in the solution manual simply assumes a set of four values of intermediate pressure (that somehow magically the actual intermediate pressure lies within!): 
$$P_2 = \begin{pmatrix}725\\750\\775\\800\end{pmatrix} \text{kPa}$$

And for each pressure in the set, the one that results in an equal power output from the two turbines (or the closest value to $\triangle W = 0$) is the actual intermediate pressure (After some trials).

> and we interpolate linearly to find the value of $P_2$ for which the work difference is zero:

Comment: I'm exactly looking for that magic...

Comment: @MohammadHoseinKhalili there is no way to find it (with the given data) except for some trials and errors. the solution just narrows the number of these trials with this assumption nothing more.

Comment: can you read my own idea:
if working isen. then s3=s2=s1, so we can determine the state 3 properties,so H2(isen)=(H1+H3)/2 , is it correct?

Comment: @MohammadHoseinKhalili No, $S_1 = S_2 = S_3$ is only valid if we are expanding directly using two successive isentropic turbines, the second turbine makes ${S_3}_{is}$ different from the values of entropy of states one and two in the isentropic case.

Comment: that's funny you know...how am i supposed to think of around 700kpa in my exam..

Comment: @MohammadHoseinKhalili I don't see this type of problems an exam material. But you could start with assuming to pressure values far from each other and calculate the power difference in each case, if one value is +ve and the other is -ve then you are in between .. and so on.

Comment: in Iran,every odd and magically problem is an exam material,professors aren't relying much on concepts.

Comment: @MohammadHoseinKhalili The idea behind the interpolation is a concept. Usually any problem that requires iterations without providing the students with an educated guess of where to start is unsuiteable for an exam is all.

Comment: @idkfa of course,i do a lot of interpolations everyday in fluid mechanics,thermodynamics and so on and that's absolutely an important thing,i just meant that magical first guess about pressure.